# Adding metadata for films/TV shows on Linux

Tags: mp4, linux, handbrake

I am looking for an open-source solution for automatically pulling films/TV shows informations. I've found MetaX (Windows only) and Subler (MacOSX only) from a post [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/91790/adding-metadata-for-films-tv-shows-in-itunes). Apparently metadata sources can be found from: TVDB, TheMovieDB, Amazon, and tagChimp, as well as IMDB, ref [here](http://www.danhinsley.com/).

I know I can use [MP4Box](http://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/mp4box/) (or libav/ffmpeg) to easily add metadata (including Cover Art), but really what I would like is a script and/or GUI to easily **retrieve** metadata (plot summary, cast and crew, genre, release data, Cover Art as JPEG...).

Some people suggested using [VLC](http://www.tweaking4all.com/home-theatre/adding-movie-information-metadata-to-mp4-m4v/#linux_vlc) on Linux. But I cannot get anything to work over here (using debian/jessie amd64). Neither the *“Download Cover Art”*, nor the *“Add Cover Art”* seems to work.

[image: VLC Screenshot]

The first one does nothing, the second one print this on the console:

```
[00007f3fc4567d38] taglib meta writer error: File /tmp/big_buck_bunny_480p_h264.mov can't be opened for tag writing
```

Bonus point: if this could be integrated to [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/), that would be awesome.

Comment: Do you have any sources that can be used to pull these informations in an automated manner? [ffmpeg can handle metadata](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Metadata-1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research, I discover this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966503/does-imdb-provide-an-api).

So far the API for http://www.omdbapi.com has proven to be exactly what I wanted. For completeness, I found those command line tools helpful:

- https://github.com/xbgmsharp/allocine
- https://github.com/bgr/imdb-cli

And on debian:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-imdbp
```